# Updating 3rd tier document in subarray

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insert-update, arrays, subdocument

I have a document as follows (in a Projects collection):

```
      title: "title"
      company: "company"
      companyID: "companyID"
      category: "category"
      starred: false
      createdAt: new Date
      tasks: [
        {
          task:'something'
          completed: false
          taskID: Random.id()
        }
        {
          task:'something'
          completed: false
          taskID: Random.id()
        }
        {
          task:'something'
          completed: false
          taskID: Random.id()
        }
      ]
```

I can set `completed: true` on a task using this method:

```
  completeTask: (projectID, taskID, ifCompleted) ->
    Projects.update {
      _id: projectID
      'tasks.taskID': taskID
    }, $set: 'tasks.$.completed': ifCompleted
    return
```

if I change my document to this:

```
{
  title: 'title.com'
  company: 'company'
  companyID: Random.id()
  category: 'category'
  starred: false
  createdAt: new Date
  categories: [
      {
        completed: true
        name: 'ideas'
        _id: Random.
        tasks: [
          {task: 'something', completed: false, taskID: Random.id()}
          {task: 'something', completed: false, taskID: Random.id()}
          {task: 'something', completed: false, taskID: Random.id()}
        ]
      }
      {
        completed: false
        name: 'development'
        _id: Random.id()
        tasks: [
          {task: 'something', completed: false, taskID: Random.id()}
          {task: 'something', completed: false, taskID: Random.id()}
          {task: 'something', completed: false, taskID: Random.id()}
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

how can I set `completed: true` on a task?

So far I have

```
completeTask: (projectID, categoryID, taskID, ifCompleted) ->
    Projects.update {
```

Comment: You cannot unless you are referencing at least one of the `category` or `task` by its index in the array.

Comment: I moved it to a separate 'Tasks' collection in the end. mongo 3.2 is supposed to be adding support for multiple $ positional selectors. thanks for the reply.